# Alter (EMPTY) table add partition COLUMN

Tags: hadoop, hive

HDP-2.5.0.0 using Ambari  2.4.0.1

There are several SQL Server and Oracle database schema that need to imported to HDFS/Hive.

The current approach is working fine :

1. Sqoop import from RDBMS to HDFS in avro format
2. Creation of a Hive external table atop the avro files viz. dataaggregate_avro_compressed
3. Create the final table from the step.2. **AUTOMATE this step**
4. Insert data from table in Step 2. to the final table

Now, the Step3. table has to be ORC + COMPRESSED + **PARTITIONED** and possibly, MANAGED. Manually, following can be done :

```
CREATE TABLE `dataaggregate_orc_empty`( ......)PARTITIONED BY (`datedimensionid` bigint)  ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat' TBLPROPERTIES ('orc.compress'='ZLIB');
```

But it's **AUTOMATIC creation is a challenge**, I'm struggling with the following approaches :

- **CTAS empty table**

  CREATE TABLE dataaggregate_orc_empty LIKE dataaggregate_avro_compressed ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat' TBLPROPERTIES ('orc.compress'='ZLIB');

Now, this **table contains the partition column datedimensionid** which needs to be removed from the table but an 'alter table drop column' is not supported

- CTAS using [REGEX column spec](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-REGEXColumnSpecification). :

  set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none;
  CREATE TABLE dataaggregate_orc_empty AS SELECT `(datedimensionid)?+.+` FROM dataaggregate_avro_compressed limit 0;

This creates the table without the partition column datedimensionid but now **how to alter this empty table to include the partition column**, this is where even the first approach hits the wall ! The [documentation talks about adding partitions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AddPartitions) with a specification but I don't have one at this stage - I just want this table to be alike the one created manually(**shown in the beginning of the post**).

How shall I proceed ?

Comment: `HiveMetaStoreClient` may help your requirement. I gave sample approach in this way we modified partitions. you can give a try

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to connect [`HiveMetaStoreClient`](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.13.1/api/metastore/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/HiveMetaStoreClient.html) and you can use method `alter partition` .

In this class along with columns all the other information like partitions can be extracted. pls. see example client and methods.
[image]

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf;

// test program
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        HiveConf hiveConf = new HiveConf();
        hiveConf.setIntVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTORETHRIFTCONNECTIONRETRIES, 3);
        hiveConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTOREURIS, "thrift://host:port");

        HiveMetaStoreConnector hiveMetaStoreConnector = new HiveMetaStoreConnector(hiveConf);
        if(hiveMetaStoreConnector != null){
            System.out.print(hiveMetaStoreConnector.getAllPartitionInfo("tablename"));
        }
    }
}


// define a class like this

import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.FieldSchema;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.MetaException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.Partition;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.hive_metastoreConstants;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive;
import org.apache.thrift.TException;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class HiveMetaStoreConnector {
    private HiveConf hiveConf;
    HiveMetaStoreClient hiveMetaStoreClient;

    public HiveMetaStoreConnector(String msAddr, String msPort){
        try {
            hiveConf = new HiveConf();
            hiveConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTOREURIS, msAddr+":"+ msPort);
            hiveMetaStoreClient = new HiveMetaStoreClient(hiveConf);
        } catch (MetaException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Constructor error");
            System.err.println(e.toString());
            System.exit(-100);
        }
    }

    public HiveMetaStoreConnector(HiveConf hiveConf){
        try {
            this.hiveConf = hiveConf;
            hiveMetaStoreClient = new HiveMetaStoreClient(hiveConf);
        } catch (MetaException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Constructor error");
            System.err.println(e.toString());
            System.exit(-100);
        }
    }

    public String getAllPartitionInfo(String dbName){
        List<String> res = Lists.newArrayList();
        try {
            List<String> tableList = hiveMetaStoreClient.getAllTables(dbName);
            for(String tableName:tableList){
                res.addAll(getTablePartitionInformation(dbName,tableName));
            }
        } catch (MetaException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("getAllTableStatistic error");
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            System.exit(-100);
        }

        return Joiner.on("\n").join(res);
    }

    public List<String> getTablePartitionInformation(String dbName, String tableName){
        List<String> partitionsInfo = Lists.newArrayList();
        try {
            List<String> partitionNames = hiveMetaStoreClient.listPartitionNames(dbName,tableName, (short) 10000);
            List<Partition> partitions = hiveMetaStoreClient.listPartitions(dbName,tableName, (short) 10000);
            for(Partition partition:partitions){
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                sb.append(tableName);
                sb.append("\t");
                List<String> partitionValues = partition.getValues();
                if(partitionValues.size()<4){
                    int size = partitionValues.size();
                    for(int j=0; j<4-size;j++){
                        partitionValues.add("null");
                    }
                }
                sb.append(Joiner.on("\t").join(partitionValues));
                sb.append("\t");
                DateTime createDate = new DateTime((long)partition.getCreateTime()*1000);
                sb.append(createDate.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
                partitionsInfo.add(sb.toString());
            }

        } catch (TException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"error for request on" + tableName});
        }

        return partitionsInfo;
    }

    public String getAllTableStatistic(String dbName){
        List<String> res = Lists.newArrayList();
        try {
            List<String> tableList = hiveMetaStoreClient.getAllTables(dbName);
            for(String tableName:tableList){
                res.addAll(getTableColumnsInformation(dbName,tableName));
            }
        } catch (MetaException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("getAllTableStatistic error");
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            System.exit(-100);
        }

        return Joiner.on("\n").join(res);
    }

    public List<String> getTableColumnsInformation(String dbName, String tableName){
        try {
            List<FieldSchema> fields = hiveMetaStoreClient.getFields(dbName, tableName);
            List<String> infs = Lists.newArrayList();
            int cnt = 0;
            for(FieldSchema fs : fields){
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                sb.append(tableName);
                sb.append("\t");
                sb.append(cnt);
                sb.append("\t");
                cnt++;
                sb.append(fs.getName());
                sb.append("\t");
                sb.append(fs.getType());
                sb.append("\t");
                sb.append(fs.getComment());
                infs.add(sb.toString());
            }

            return infs;

        } catch (TException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("getTableColumnsInformation error");
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            System.exit(-100);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But the methods in the class, e.g; add_partition(Partition new_part) doesn't seem to address my problem - adding a partition column to an empty table i.e no data or values for the partition.

Comment: have you tried that ? AFAIK its should work with empty table as well

Comment: this class HiveMetaStoreClient  used by other sql engines to have inter-operablity with hive metastore level